# Show correct UTC and offset for live event start time using New York timezone

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to show an event start time with the correct UTC offset (New York Timezone), so normally it would show this:

```
June 01, 2001 @ 20:00 UTC-4
```

But if the event starts during Daylight Saving months the event output would automatically show UTC-5, as 8pm in New York then would be UTC-5:

```
December 01, 2001 @ 20:00 UTC-5
```

Is there a way to do this?

With DateTime the closest I can get is without showing the timezone:

```
'F j, Y @ G:i'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have the hours delivered to you with the DateTime Format Option "P" and then format the desired result with sprintf.

```
function tzUTC(DateTimeInterface $date)
{
  $tzHours = (int)$date->format('P');
  return sprintf('UTC%+1d',$tzHours);
}
```

Example:

```
$date = new DateTime('now',new DateTimezone('America/New_York'));
echo $date->format('F j, Y @ G:i ').tzUTC($date);
```

Output:

```
September 21, 2021 @ 9:10 UTC-4
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options, but none of them are exactly what you're looking for. You might have to do a bit of manipulation.

With default formatters, you have `O` (+0200), `P` or `p` (+02:00), and `T` (EST, MDT, +05). See https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php under timezone identifiers. It won't add the UTC, but you can add it in yourself like `'F j, Y @ G:i \U\T\CP'`, which currently gives me `"September 21, 2021 @ 7:51 UTC-04:00"`.

The other option, if you want just the number, is to format it yourself. With the DateTime class, you have `getOffset()`, which returns the offset in seconds. With a bit of math, you can get the number

```
$date = new DateTime();
$offset = $date->getOffset() / 60 / 60; // Divide by 60 seconds to a minute, 60 minutes to an hour
$formatted_date = $date->format('F j, Y @ G:i'). " UTC$offset"; 
// "September 21, 2021 @ 7:52 UTC-4"
```